# Line where "hobby" starts: is this ontopic?

Tags: discussion

I'm not really sure if my problem is "home improvement" enough, or is too much 'hobby', so I thought to check over @ meta.DIY first :)

Without producing everything here, the question is basically about mounting a tablet to a wall (kitchen) to create a media center // remote for media server.  Networking, software etc are all fine, the only problem I still have is the actual mounting-on-the-wall part, options I have concerning rotation, etc etc.

Would this be considered off-topic? I think it fits the bill here, but on the other hand, I'm not sure I would have "asked a home contractor" this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking how to mount something on a wall is certainly on topic, and something I would ask a contractor if I was paying someone to do the job for me. I'd want to know that what they were proposing was fit for purpose.

However, search first to see if there's an existing question about mounting televisions etc, that might be able to help you. If you don't find anything ask away.

Comment: Maybe the definition of "home contractor" is somewhat off in my brain then (lost in translation?) ;D. Obviously I'll be a good exchanger and search first :). Thanks!

Comment: @Nanne - "Contractor" here is in the US sense. In the UK we'd probably say "Builder".

Comment: My handicap is the Dutch language _and_ relatively inactive in DIY so I'm not sure I would've understood 'builder' any better :). I know what the word means obviously, but for some reason it says "Build a wall, make a roof, add concrete in great amounts" to me ;) *adjusts image*. All clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

We've got questions on how to hang pictures, how to mount televisions, and everything in between. So asking how to wall mount a tablet appears to be on-topic to me. As long as the question is about mounting an object to the building, I don't think it makes a difference what the object is. But once you get away from the mounting question, into perhaps the aesthetics or how to build what you're mounting on the wall, it risks becoming off-topic.